# How can I use both Sogou Pinyin and Dead Keys on Ubuntu or Kylin?

Tags: kylin, dead-keys

I need to use both Chinese input and special characters like é and ü for other languages. I used to be able to do this on Ubuntu 14.04 by customizing fcitx for Chinese input and switching between this and English International with Dead Keys, but the quality of Chinese character input is lower than Sogou's.

I have just installed Ubuntu Kylin in English to give it a try, and at first it didn't have Sogou input enabled; it was possible to switch keyboard languages but Dead Key functionality was intermittent. I then installed Sogou, by downloading the .deb from their website. This, however, seems to override the normal keyboard language switch between English with Dead Keys and other languages - my only keyboard choices now are standard (no dead keys) characters and Chinese pinyin input.

Is it possible to have both functionalities on the same system?

Comment: Found the answer myself by realizing I was mixing up some Chinese characters in my mind, explained below.

Answer (score 0):

Sogou's settings option, accessed from the drop-down keyboard menu at the top of the screen, supersedes the old keyboard settings panel. Adding English International With Dead Keys from this menu (and NOT from the standard Ubuntu Keyboard Settings menu) sorts the problem out.

The Chinese command to access this option on the menu is 配置.